# "Source image could not be found" when using Symfony3 LiipImageBundle

Tags: php, symfony, liipimaginebundle, vichuploaderbundle

I have the following error message in my Symfony3 application:

[image: error page]

This is the Twig code, along with the imagine_filter:

[image: Code in Twig + imagine_filter]

This is the local URL generated after applying the LiipImage filter:

> localhost/symfony3/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/resolve/my_thumb/symfony3/web/images/uploads/5745ce2e628a9.png

This is my config for liipimage and vichuploader:

```
# VichUploader Configuration
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm # or mongodb or propel or phpcr
    twig: true
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/uploads
            upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/uploads/
            namer:              vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
            inject_on_load:     true
            delete_on_update:   true
            delete_on_remove:   true

# liip_imagine Configuration
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~


    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        my_thumb:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [120, 90], mode: outbound }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try re-uploading image. your image doesnot exists physically

Comment: thank you sir
image is already existe when i loaded without 'imagine_filter'.
I think that the problem in the path: `"C:\wamp\www\symfony3\app/../web/symfony3/web/images/uploads/5745ce2e628a9.png"`
exactly the two points, slash and the antislash _\app/../web/_

**how i can fix this!**

Comment: have you try re uploading images ? and empty the cache folder ?

Comment: hi @Noman can you help me to fix it

Comment: LiipImageBundle can't generate or create any cache folder or file because the image source not found in [C:\wamp\www\symfony3\app/../web/symfony3/web/images/uploads/5745ce2e628a9.png]